# How can I filter RETURNING *?

Tags: postgresql, insert-update, postgresql-9.5, sql-returning

I have the following scenario.  I have a table that has an IsDeleted flag I set for doing a 'soft delete' of records.  I am doing an UPSERT where I am adding, modifying and flagging as deleted some records.  I want to exclude records that have been flagged as deleted from the RETURNING statement.  I have attempted to just append `WHERE tbltest_IsDeleted = 0` to the end of the following SQL but it gives me the error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

How can I filter the results of the `RETURNING *` in the following statement?

```
INSERT INTO tbltest (
    tbltest_ID,
    tbltest_Name,
    tbltest_Description,
    tbltest_IsDeleted) 
VALUES 
(DEFAULT, 'new record','new record description', 0),
(4, 'modified record name','modified record description', 0),
(5, 'existing record name','existing record description', 1)
ON CONFLICT (tbltest_ID) DO UPDATE SET (
    tbltest_Name,
    tbltest_Description,
    tbltest_IsDeleted) = (
    excluded.tbltest_Name,
    excluded.tbltest_Description,
    excluded.tbltest_IsDeleted) RETURNING *;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out, here is how I was able to do it:

```
WITH rows AS (
    INSERT INTO tbltest (
            tbltest_ID,
            tbltest_Name,
            tbltest_Description,
            tbltest_IsDeleted) 
    VALUES 
    (DEFAULT, 'new record','new record description', 0),
    (4, 'modified record name','modified record description', 0),
    (5, 'existing record name','existing record description', 1)
    ON CONFLICT (tbltest_ID) DO UPDATE SET (
            tbltest_Name,
            tbltest_Description,
            tbltest_IsDeleted) = (
            excluded.tbltest_Name,
            excluded.tbltest_Description,
            excluded.tbltest_IsDeleted) RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE rows.tbltest_IsDeleted = 0
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time ;-)